# Add two numbers works in Jupyter, but generates a wrong answer in LeetCode

Tags: python-3.x, list, linked-list, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I'm trying the "add two numbers" (linked list) problem in leetcode. The code that I wrote works fine in Jupyter notebook and returns the correct answer:

```
def list_to_digits(lst):
    lst.reverse()
    strings = map(str, lst) 
    a_string = "". join(strings)
    an_integer = int(a_string)
    return an_integer

def Convert_IntegersToList(integers):
    res = list(map(int, str(integers))) 
    res.reverse()
    return(res)

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        integered_l1 = self.list_to_digits(l1)
        integered_l2 = self.list_to_digits(l2)
        sum_Integers = integered_l1 + integered_l2
        list_ofSum = self.Convert_IntegersToList(sum_Integers)
        return(list_ofSum)
```

For example, for the following:

```
l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [5,6,4]
output_list = Solution().addTwoNumbers(l1,l2)
print(output_list)
```

this code returns: [7, 0, 8] which is the correct result. When I run the same code in leetcode however, it returns the following error:

> ListNode object has no attribute reverse

this error happens in line *lst.reverse()* from function *list_to_digits*.
Then I tried using two functions for converting between nodeList and python list according to [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/174970/Help-with-ListNode-(Python)). This time, I have something like this:

```
class Solution:

    def listnode_to_pylist(self, listnode):
        ret = []
        while True:
            ret.append(listnode.val)
            if listnode.next != None:
                listnode = listnode.next
            else:
                return ret
        
    def pylist_to_listnode(self, pylist, link_count):
        if len(pylist) > 1:
            ret = precompiled.listnode.ListNode(pylist.pop())
            ret.next = self.pylist_to_listnode(pylist, link_count)
            return ret
        else:
            return precompiled.listnode.ListNode(pylist.pop(), None)    

    def list_to_digits(self, lst):
        lst.reverse()
        strings = map(str, lst) 
        a_string = "". join(strings)
        an_integer = int(a_string)
        return an_integer

    def Convert_IntegersToList(self, integers):
        res = list(map(int, str(integers))) 
        res.reverse()
        return(res)
    
  
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        l1_ = self.listnode_to_pylist(l1)
        l2_ = self.listnode_to_pylist(l2)
        integered_list1 = self.list_to_digits(l1_)
        integered_list2 = self.list_to_digits(l2_)
        sum_Integers = integered_list1 + integered_list2
        list_ofSum = self.Convert_IntegersToList(sum_Integers)
    
        return(self.pylist_to_listnode(list_ofSum, len(list_ofSum)))
```

This code works in leetCode, but it returns the resulting list in the reverse order. For example, for the above example it returns: [8,0,7] (and I tried removing the list reverse line, but still the returned list is in the reverse order). Interestingly, when I run the modified code in Jupyter notebook, it throws the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong in each of these situations and how to fix it. Any idea how I can correct each of these two codes such that it works in leetcode and how to fix the error for the latter code in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: The first code is wrong if you think about it. The parameter `lst` will be whatever was passed into the function. Inside of `addTwoNumbers`, you're passing `listnode_to_pylist` `l1` and `l2` which are `ListNode`s according to the type hints. `ListNode`s don't have a `reverse` method in this code.

Comment: I can see what you're saying about the first code, I remove listNode class from it and it still works in Jupyter, which shows as you said, the input is just a list, not the lobject list defined by listNode class. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I'm also confused about your comment on listnode_to_pylist which appears in the second code not the first one. Again can you provide a solution for the second code and why the result list in leetcode is reversed?